# Validity of Ampère's law in terms of $H$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

We know that the auxiliary magnetic field $\bf{H}$ is

$$\mathbf{H}=\frac{1}{\mu_{0}} \mathbf{B}-\mathbf{M}$$

and
$$\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J}_{f}$$
but this differential equation is generally not valid at the boundary of a  magnetized body due to an abrupt change in the magnetisation $\mathbf{M}$ at the boundary.

From this differential equation follows
$$\oint \mathbf{H} \cdot d \mathbf{l}=I_{f_{\mathrm{enc}}}$$
Is this integral equation valid if applied across a boundary of a magnetized material,(that is one end of the integral is inside the magnetised body and the other is out of it)? Or does it inherit any problems from its differential form?

**EDIT:** I think my question isn't clear so I'll add:

We derive the loop integral from the curl using stokes theorem. However the curl is not defined on the boundary so is the loop integral well defined? Another way of saying is that: can I use stokes theorem when the curl of function isn't defined on some region? –

Comment: Why would the equation curl H  = j_f not be valid on the boundary? I think it is.

Comment: The magnetisation it's discontinuous,so it's derivatives will have a singularity imho

Comment: Yes current is singular on the boundary but these equations are still valid in distribution sense.

Comment: What troubles me is how we can apply Stokes theorem for a discontinuous function. Do you have any idea where to look it up dear Jan Lalinsky. I also asked it on MSE, no response :( here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034965/using-stokes-theorem-on-a-discontinuous-function

Comment: You can try some older books on vector analysis, A. P. Wills comes to mind. The general rule is if the expression is linear in vector field, delta-like singularities pose no problem and everything including Gauss-Ostrogradskii and Stokes' theorem works. Just do not use integration surface/curve that runs through the singularity, that does not work well - the singularity has to be either inside or outside.

Comment: So a line integral that cuts ( i.e intersects the singularity and goes on without moving along the singularities) is no problem?

Comment: It depends on type of singularity. The Ampere law integral for a path that crosses magnetized body has no problem, H has no singularity there. If the Ampere integral path goes through a line current, then there is a problem - the integral is either zero or $I$ depending on whether the current line crosses a surface defined by the loop or not, so it is not clear what value to assign to the integral in case the singularity is on the integration path.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the question, the answer lies in the 6.3.3 paragraph of Griffiths' book. Yes, it does inherit the discontinuity. In this case, you could still use the differential equation just above and just below the discontinuity, and taking an integration path that crosses the boundary will give you boundary conditions for the magnetic field and for the auxiliary field. Another reference is this:

https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/EM-913/section6-Magnetostatics.pdf

Post-EDIT:

Yes, you can still use the theorem, if you are cautious with the domains of integration. The loop integral will be defined even in case of discontinuity because of what I said in the comments.

Comment: So is the loop integral not valid!

Comment: What do you mean with not valid?

Comment: I apologize for my perhaps bad way of putting things. We derive the loop integral from the curl using stokes theorem. However the curl is not defined on the boundary so is the loop integral well defined? Another way of saying is that: can I use stokes theorem when the curl of function isn't defined on some region?

Comment: Yes, I think it boils down to the discontinuity region being a set of null measure, i.e. just the boundary between the two magnetizations and since it's all finite (nothing diverges) it won't contribute to the integral.

Comment: Any mathematics you might want to add?

Comment: What exactly do you need? $\boldsymbol{H}$ is well defined everywhere except for the boundary. When you take its contour integral you can view it as $\boldsymbol{H}$ multiplied by a step function, so you divide the integrals in two parts, one above and one beyond the boundary and this way everything is well defined

Comment: Regardless of the value of $\boldsymbol{H}$ at the boundary, the intersection between the contour you're integrating over and the boundary has null measure as it is just a set of two points, so the contribution to the integral is also null.

Comment: I agree that one can write down a line integral  can we apply the  Stokes theorem even if we've a discontinues function?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In case you need more help, we should move to the chat to avoid too many comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120066/discussion-between-yasir-sadiq-and-karim-chahine).

Answer (score 2):

The contour integral across the boundary should not be considered as the direct application of Stoke's theorem in this area, but in a spirit similar to the principle of analytical continuation.

The Stokes' theorem

$$
\oint_C \mathbf{H}\times d\bf{l} = \iint_A \boldsymbol\nabla \times \mathbf{H}\cdot d\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{J}_{\text{f,enclosed}}.
$$

This relation is applicable when $\boldsymbol\nabla \times \bf{H}$ is existed.It is, of course, not hold when $\boldsymbol\nabla \times \bf{H}$ diverges.

In region across the boundary, even though $\boldsymbol\nabla \times \bf{H}$ diverges, the area integral failed, but the contour integral is still working. We then adopt the contour integral as the definition, extended to such regions.

Therefore, the relation

$$
\oint_C \bf{H} \times d\bf{l} = \bf{J}_{\text{f,enclosed}}.
$$

is an analytical continuation into the across-boundary region, even the $\nabla \times \bf{H}$ diverges therein.

Similarly, $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\bf{E}$ diverges at $r=0$ for $1/r^2$ field, but the surface integral still working there

$$
\iint \mathbf{E}\cdot d\bf{A}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}
$$

We thus adopt the result from surface integral to define the strength of divergence.

$$
 \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2} = -4\pi \delta(r).
$$

Comment: Thank you could you explain as to why the contour integral works?

Comment: @YasirSadiq The integral is well defined for a piece-wise continuous function. Means that For each point, there exists a finite neighbor region, then the integral can be given an operational definition.

Comment: @YasirSadiq - You may find the following useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780715/177342

Answer (score 2):

> Is this integral equation valid if applied across a boundary of a magnetized material,(that is one end of the integral is inside the magnetised body and the other is out of it)? Or does it inherit any problems from its differential form?

There is an assumption regarding this boundary condition that is often overlooked for various reasons, but can sometimes become problematic.  The limitations of this assumption are discussed in detail in Sections I.5 and I.6 of *Classical Electrodynamics, Third Edition* by John D. Jackson (i.e., blue cover version).  So we start with:
$$
\oint_{C} \ \mathbf{H} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \int_{S'} \ da \ \left[ \mathbf{j} + \partial_{t} \mathbf{D} \right] \cdot \mathbf{n}' \tag{0}
$$
where $\mathbf{H}$ is the magnetic field (technically, $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic induction), $\mathbf{D}$ is the electric displacement, $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density (specifically the *macroscopic* average current density, see pages 248--258 in Jackson's book for definition and derivation), $S'$ is a closed surface with an outward unit normal $\mathbf{n}'$, and $\partial_{t} = \tfrac{ \partial }{ \partial t }$.

Typically one sweeps the following under the rug, as it were.  There can be a surface current density, $\mathbf{K}$, that exists in a thin layer no thicker than one electron [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) on the surface of the conducting material either caused by time-varying fields or merely present due to some source.  In such scenarios, the right-hand side of Equation 0 changes to:
$$
\int_{S'} \ da \ \left[ \mathbf{j} + \partial_{t} \mathbf{D} \right] \cdot \mathbf{t} = \mathbf{K} \cdot \mathbf{t} \ \Delta l \tag{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{t}$ is the unit vector transverse to the surface $S'$ and $\Delta l$ is the scale length of the pill box transverse to the surface $S'$.

There is another issue that arises at such a boundary involving what Jackson refers to as truly *microscopic* surface charge densities, i.e., $\rho\left( x \right) = \sigma \delta\left( x \right)$ where $\sigma$ is the average surface charge density and $\delta\left( x \right)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  The idealized scenario we are taught in class is that $\sigma$ exists on the surface and that it has zero thickness, i.e., no charge density inside conductors, only on the surface.  However, the truth is that $\rho\left( x \right)$ is confined to within $\pm 2$ angstroms of the ''surface'' of the ionic distribution.  For nearly all purposes, there is a discontinuity in the electric field at this boundary but in reality it likely varies over a finite length comparable to a few atomic widths or so.

> However the curl is not defined on the boundary so is the loop integral well defined? Another way of saying is that: can I use stokes theorem when the curl of function isn't defined on some region?

It depends on what you are doing.  Are you testing what Jackson would call the *microscopic* or the *macroscopic*?  If the latter, things are much easier and the right-hand side of Equation 0 is can vanish if there is no significant surface current density, $\mathbf{K}$, at the boundary.  Even if present, one can still work with Equation 0 or 1, depending on scenario, and get meaningful results for *macroscopic* approximations.

**Side Note**
I did not rederive Jackson's definition of *microscopic* vs *macroscopic* because it's 10 pages in his book and not really necessary here.  It basically involves noting the difference between spatial and temporal ansemble averages and why spatial are the correct choice then lots of details as to why XYZ is okay under WUV limits.  The distinction in regards to this question is whether the OP wants to properly model $\mathbf{H}$ across the boundary on scales down to the atomic or if they are okay with the typical, larger scale approximations of micrometers and up (give or take).

Comment: Dear Honeste vivere,  I'm studying your answer. Forgive me for not currently accepting your answer for the math to my level is higher . I appreciate the time you took to write this answer.

Comment: @YasirSadiq - No worries.  I've gone through those sections in gory detail a few times and still need to revisit them from time to time.  There are many things we _sweep under the rug_, so to speak, without realizing it.

Comment: These things which are unmentioned hurt most people like me who have no person in real to go to, to ask for help.

Comment: @YasirSadiq - If it helps, they are not omitted during discussion for malicious purposes.  Generally the background required to understand the consequences of including such effects are beyond starting students.  However, it is always a good idea to ask about the limits of various theorems, "laws," and approximations to gain an intuitive understanding of the problem.  My answer is basically stating that the contour integral is perfectly fine if you don't care about microphysical scales and processes.  In math, it's valid because the assumptions impose exactness.

Comment: Hi, has the bounty added to your account?

Comment: @Kashmiri - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ampère's law for $\mathbf B$ to get the total current. Then subtract the bound current from the result to get the free current, if needed.

Comment: Interesting to see that this gets downvoted. It is perhaps too easy and straightforward. What kind of virtual photons actually carry H?

Comment: Dear my2cts I did not downvote it. I almost never downvote anything. I'm glad that you've added something although it doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: The usual excellent users who vote negative without reading the answer. +1