# What is the governing differential equation on the interface of two areas with different permeabilities in magnetostatics?

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

The boundary condition requires that parallel component of magnetic field intensity to be continuous on the interface of two adjacent media with different permeabilities. for example on a 2d plane in cartesian coordinates, for a boundary that is located on $x=x_b$ and is parallel to y-axis, we have:
$$\lim_{x \to x_b^+} H_y = \lim_{x \to x_b^-} H_y$$
this suggests that the parallel component of flux density and therefore the normal derivative of potential is not continuous due to different permeabilities.
$$\lim_{x \to x_b^+} \frac{1}{\mu_1}B_y = \lim_{x \to x_b^-} \frac{1}{\mu_2}B_y$$
$$\lim_{x \to x_b^+} \frac{1}{\mu_1}\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x} = \lim_{x \to x_b^-} \frac{1}{\mu_2}\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}$$
now since $A_z$ is no longer differentiable, hence the laplace equation should not be satisfied on the boundary.
the question is what is the governing differential equation on a point that is exactly on the boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's start with the assumption/definition that $\mathbf{B} = \mu \mathbf{H}$, where $\mathbf{H}$ is called the magnetic field, $\mathbf{B}$ is called the magnetic induction, and $\mu$ is the [permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) of the substance/medium.  As discussed in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616752/59023), there can be a finite surface current density, $\mathbf{K}$, on the boundary of a conductor.  This is illustrated using the usual boundary condition of:
$$
\oint_{C} \ \mathbf{H} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \int_{S'} \ da \ \left[ \mathbf{j} + \partial_{t} \mathbf{D} \right] \cdot \mathbf{n}' \tag{0}
$$
where $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density (specifically the *macroscopic* average current density, [see pages 248--258 in *Jackson*, [1999] book for definition and derivation]), $S'$ is a closed surface with an outward unit normal $\mathbf{n}'$, and $\partial_{t} = \tfrac{ \partial }{ \partial t }$.

It turns out that in the limit where there is a finite $\mathbf{K}$ the right-hand side of Equation 0 goes to $\mathbf{K} \cdot \mathbf{t} \ \Delta l$, where $\mathbf{t}$ is the unit vector transverse to the surface $S'$ and $\Delta l$ is the scale length of the pill box transverse to the surface $S'$.  In this limit, the boundary conditions between two media of different permeabilities go to:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{n} \cdot \left( \mathbf{B}_{2} - \mathbf{B}_{1} \right) & = 0 \tag{1a} \\
  \mathbf{H}_{1} \cdot \mathbf{n} & = \frac{ \mu_{1} }{ \mu_{2} } \left( \mathbf{H}_{2} \cdot \mathbf{n} \right) \tag{1b} \\
  \mathbf{n} \times \left( \mathbf{H}_{2} - \mathbf{H}_{1} \right) & = \mathbf{K} \tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
where subscripts $1$ and $2$ refer to the two different regions.  Note this assumes that $\mu$ is not a function of $\mathbf{H}$, i.e., the linear limit [e.g., see pages 193--194 in *Jackson*, [1999]].

For discussion of induced eddy currents and magnetic diffusion, see pages 219--223 in *Jackson* [1999].

> the question is what is the governing differential equation on a point that is exactly on the boundary?

As I mention above, there can be abrupt changes right at the boundary for various reasons (e.g., induced currents).  However, these are often confined to regions one or less [skin depths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) from the surface.  For copper at room temperature, the skin depth is $\sim0.0652 \left( \nu\left[ Hz \right] \right)^{-1/2}$ m.  That is, for incident electromagnetic fluctuations at frequencies above ~100 MHz the skin depth is on the order of microns.  For extremely thin materials, this could pose a problem for such low frequencies but would be negligible for any sufficiently thick material.

So in the limit that we care about the exact conditions across the boundary, then we need to use Equation 0 with the modification allowing for a finite $\mathbf{K}$ flowing along the surface.

## **References**

- J.D. Jackson, *Classical Electrodynamics*, Third Edition, John Wiley & Sons, Inc., New York, NY, 1999.

Comment: thank for thorough answer. you mentioned the general boundary condition $n \times (H_2 - H_1) = K$. In my case there is no surface current density defined so the right hand side vanishes, leading to the continuity of field intensity.

Comment: what I got from the answer is that due to singularity on the boundary, we cannot derive a differential equation; however in microscopic scale there is finite interval(skin-size) at which there is a finite-slope change through the interface. Is that true? if it is regardless of physical manner, and to a mathematical sense, can we say that since laplace equation cannot be defined on the boundary, we only need to satisfy boundary condition?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi - Actually, the surface current density I mentioned, it can exist in an extremely thin layer at the boundary due to various things and need not be prescribed or defined in the general sense.  That is the point of my answer, namely, that there can be a finite $\mathbf{K}$ at the boundary but you need not always include that in your solving Maxwell's equations across the boundary.

Comment: this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/surface-current-density
states that: "A surface current density Js exists at an interface only in certain situations such as an impressed source layer, on the surface of superconductors, and, for time-varying fields, on the surface of perfect electrical conductors (σ → ∞) (Paul et al., 1998)."
I don't think in magnetostatic problem, there exists a surface current.